# Constructing Javascript Array from Server Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am getting this Data inside server from my AJAX call

```
{jobs:[{Dater:"2010-01-01",INCPU:"1",OUTCPU:"1"},{Dater:"2010-01-02",INCPU:"2",O
UTCPU:"2"},{Dater:"2010-01-03",INCPU:"3",OUTCPU:"3"}]
```

This is my AJAX Call

From this call , i am trying to construct this type of Array inside my JSP

```
var MyData = [{date:'2010-01-01',INCPU:"1",OUTCPU:"1"},{date:'2010-01-01',INCPU:"1",OUTCPU:"1"}];

 ****var constructarray =[];****    

 jQuery.ajax({ 
       url: '/HumblFin/Serv', 
       success: function(data) { 
          drawChart(data);
 },

function drawChart(data)
{    
 for(var i = 0 ; i<=data.jobs.length ; i++)
 {
   constructarray .push(data.jobs.Dater[i]);  
   constructarray .push(data.jobs.INCPU[i]);  
   constructarray .push(data.jobs.OUTCPU[i]);  
 }
}
```

I have put up an alert of my constructarray
But unfortunately is printling only ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Could anybody please help me .

Comment: This question is totally uncomprehensible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i<=data.jobs.length ; i++)
{
  constructarray .push(data.jobs[i].Dater);  
  constructarray .push(data.jobs[i].INCPU);  
  constructarray .push(data.jobs[i].OUTCPU);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the syntax of JSP but what you need is to convert JSON into class. Its called Deserializing of JSON into system object.

There must be some support in JSP to work with JSON or you can use open libraries. e.g.

http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/

also check this example
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/json-jsp-example.shtml

Comment: Hey thanks for the response , the question is not related to JSON . Its about constructing Javascript array in the specified format .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo, but the format of your JSON data string you say you are getting back is incorrect.  You are missing an ending "}".  It should look like below:

```
{jobs:[{Dater:"2010-01-01",INCPU:"1",OUTCPU:"1"},{Dater:"2010-01-02",INCPU:"2",OUTCPU:"2"},{Dater:"2010-01-03",INCPU:"3",OUTCPU:"3"}]}
```

Second, you should be using `data.jobs[i].Dater` instead of `data.jobs.Dater[i]`.

Comment: Disregard the extra 'O' comment if you saw that a minute ago, didn't see it was part of 'OUTCPU'.

Comment: When i hardcoded as data.jobs[1].INCPU  , the value is coming properly , i think i need to check the ending flower braces 
}                     `   StringBuffer jobs = new StringBuffer("{jobs:[");

   while (rs.next()) {

    jobs.append("{id:\"" + rs.getString("id") + "\",title:\""
      + rs.getString("created") + "\"},");
   }

   jobs.setCharAt(jobs.length() - 1, ']');
   jobs.append("}");

   System.out.println(jobs.toString());`